# Showing by an example that $f'(x)$ may exist everywhere but need not be continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Let $f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ I'm asked to show that $f'(x)$ exists everywhere but is not continuous.$f'(x)=2x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right).$ We can see that $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ does not exist. It is not continuous at $x=0.$
But It does not exist everywhere? At $x=0,$ $f'(x)$ takes on many different values, it is not defined everywhere,

So Doesn't this show that the $f'(x)$ does not exist at $x=0$?

Comment: $f'(0)=0$ but $f'$ is not continuous at 0.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam No $-cos \infty$ varies between 0 and -1 as $x-> \infty$

Comment: [This is a very interesting function](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjIzp6MkrjQAhUnw1QKHVpYC2AQFggrMAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FVolterra%27s_function&usg=AFQjCNH1aUBXQVnOzfjK9Ng42X5bjE0Z6Q)

Comment: Your question is incomplete without the value of function  at $0.$ Because though $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=0$ exist $f$ is undefined at $0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$

$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(\frac{1}{x})=0.$$

Comment: Makes sense but what about my way of thinking, the result doesn't follow in two ways, what is wrong with mine?

Comment: How do you know $f(0)$?

Comment: Exactly. But it should be a part of the definition of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The original function is not even defined at 0.  The example is supposed to be defined as what you wrote with f(0)=0 additionally.  In that case the derivative you wrote is valid when $x\neq 0$.  To compute the derivative at 0 you should use the limit definition.

Comment: It is defined $f(0)=0$ $sin\frac{1}{x}$ varies between 1 and 0 and $x^2=0$ making $f(x)=0$

Comment: 1/x is not defined at 0.  f(0) is not equal to $0\sin 1/x$, you can't plug in 0 for one $x$ but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $f(0)$ is defined to be $0$. $f'(x) = 2x\sin\frac 1 x - \cos\frac 1 x $ for nonzero $x$, but at $x = 0$,
\begin{align*}
f'(0) &:=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h - 0}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2\sin\frac1 h}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} h\sin\frac1 h\\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, because $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist but $f'(0) = 0$, $f'$ is discontinuous but exists everywhere.

If you look at the requirements needed to apply rules like the product rule and chain rule at a point $c$, you see that they require that $g$ be differentiable at $c$ in order to say that $(f\circ g)'(c) = f'(g(c)) g'(c)$.  You need to perform the computation of $f'(0)$ separately, because $\frac1 0$ isn't a number, and hence $0^2\sin\frac1 0$ is not a number either, and so the formula $x^2\sin\frac1 x$ does not make any sense at $x = 0$ and the above rules cannot be applied there; the limit definition must be used instead.